# ¿Cómo puedo modificar un valor de una propiedad?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

sabeis como sería la manera correcta de cambiar el valor del booleano active, lo he intentado en la función toggleActive pero me imprime siempre 'false'

```js
<template>
  <h1>Tool list component</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:"tool-list",
  props: {
    numElements:Number,
    active: {
      type: Boolean
    },
  }, 
   
  methods: {
    toggleActive: function(){
      this.active = true; 
      console.log(this.active);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Flujo-de-datos-unidireccional El flujo de las props es unidireccional, lo que se modifica en el padre se refleja en los hijos pero no al reves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vue 2 no puede modificar un prop desde el componenete hijo. Como comento @Agustin, son unidireccional, es decir, es solo de lectura. Pero si debe modificarlo, desde el hijo puede usar un evento personalizado ver: [Emitir valor  con un evento](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event). Entonces se puede emitir un evento desde el componente hijo  y el padre lo escuchará para modificar el estado que se pasa como prop:

Componenete: **Padre**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!--toggleActive: evento personalizado (emit)-->
    <ComponenteToggle :active="active" @toggle-active="toggleActive" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import ComponenteToggle from "./ComponenteToggle.vue"
export default {
  components:{
    ComponenteToggle
  },
  data: () => ({
    active: false
  }),
  methods: {
    /**toggleActive: Es la escucha del componente hijo al dar click
    en el botón. Recibe el nuevo valor (val) y lo asigna en active que luego es 
    usado como prop**/
    toggleActive(val) {
      //this.active = val; //No toggle.
      this.active = !this.active; // toggle. Cambia al valor contrario del actual.
      
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Componenete: **Hijo**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ active }}</p>
    <button @click="toggleActive">Cambiar valor de active</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /**toggleActive: Evento click y emitir el evento
    toggle-active que usa el padre para actualizar el prop**/
    toggleActive() {
      this.$emit('toggle-active', true); //Envía true como nuevo valor.
    }
  }
}
</script>
```